# Destructor de superclases

Tags: java

cuando sobre-escribimos en una subclase el destructor y no se llama al destructor de la super-clase, dicho destructor nunca es llamado. Esto causa lagunas de memoria? 
Por ejemplo:

```
class A {
    A() {
        System.out.println("constructor A");
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
       // super.finalize();
        System.out.println("destructor A");
    }
}

class B extends  A {
    B() {
        System.out.println("constructor B");
    }

    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
       // super.finalize();
        System.out.println("destructor B");
    }
}

public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        {
            B b = new B();
        }

        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        runtime.gc();
        runtime.runFinalization();
    }
}
```

El resultado es:

```
constructor A
constructor B
destructor B
```

El destructor *A* nunca es llamado. ¿Quizás un *memory leak*?

Gracias anticipadas.
Un cordial saludo

Comment: Funciona correctamente. Tu creas un objeto B, al crearlo, se ejecuta su constructor y el constructor del padre. Después cuando finalizas, se ejecuta el destructor de B y únicamente el de B, ya que estas sobrescribiendo el método del padre. Si no hubieses añadido el destructor a B, se ejecutaría el del padre

Comment: En java no hay destructores, el garbage collector se ocupa de liberar memoria. Lo que llamas "destructor" es mas como un "finalizador", solo hace limpieza si tu quieres y a las cosas que tu quieres, pero no destruye el objeto y tampoco libera memoria. Así que a tu pregunta "*Esto causa lagunas de memoria?*" la respuesta es - no. Si quieres liberar memoria debes desreferenciar el objeto que has creado. En *finalize* no se hace nada que libere la memoria.

Comment: @EvgeniEnchev Deberías poner ese comentario (quizá con algún enlace a documentación oficial como respuesta)

Comment: @PabloLozano, en la documentación "oficial" no se dice nada sobre destructores, simplemente uno estudia java etc. Pongo unos enlaces para los curiosos - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171952/is-there-a-destructor-for-java y https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/java-destructor-why-is-it-missing/

Comment: Un "leak de memoria" se da cuando un objeto que ya no se necesita queda referenciado por algún otro objeto del sistema, lo que provoca que el garbage collector no pueda liberar ese espaicio de memoria por considerarlo todavía en uso. Cuando estas situaciones son repetitivas dentro de la ejecución del sistema, de a poco van copando la memoria disponible, por eso lo del "leak".